# UDP client (receiver) not receiving datagrams as it should

Tags: c++, udp

I am trying to receive data from one program (X-Plane 10 to be specific). It's supposed to be done by UDP connection.
The format of data sending by XPlane is (4 + n * 32) byte package (n- depending on the settings inside Xplane).
I am trying to receive it by the following code:

```
const int LEN = 256;
int server_length;
int port = 49010;

char* package = new char[LEN];

WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET mySocket;
SOCKET myBackup;
SOCKET acceptSocket;
sockaddr_in myAddress;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

//socket
if( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData ) != NO_ERROR )
{
    cerr<<"Socket Initialization: Error with WSAStartup\n";
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(10);
}

mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

if (mySocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cerr<<"Error creating socket"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(11);
}


//binding
myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
myAddress.sin_port = htons(port);

if(bind(mySocket, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, sizeof(myAddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cerr<<"Failed to connect\n";
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(14);
}

//receiving
while (true) 
{
    cout.flush();
    server_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    myAddress.sin_port = htons(port);
    recvfrom(mySocket, package, LEN, 0, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, &server_length);
    printf( "%s\n", package );
}
    return 0;
}
```

All I am receiving is DATA@ + sometimes a random symbol.

I know that the first 5 bytes of the datagrams should be "DATA@", so I know it's connecting and more or less working but I can't understand why it doesn't read the rest of data sending by Xplane.

edit:
I've found one code online and I used it in my program. The same result: DATA@...

It doesn't show anything else in the file either.

```
#define DEFAULT_PORT            49010
#define DEFAULT_COUNT           100
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH   41

int   iPort    = DEFAULT_PORT;          // Port to receive on
DWORD dwCount  = DEFAULT_COUNT,         // Number of messages to read
 dwLength = DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH; // Length of receiving buffer
BOOL  bInterface = FALSE;               // Use an interface other than
                                // default
char  szInterface[32];            // Interface to read datagrams from

//
// Function: usage:
//
// Description:
//    Print usage information and exit
//
void usage()
{
printf("usage: sender [-p:int] [-i:IP][-n:x] [-b:x]\n\n");
printf("       -p:int   Local port\n");
printf("       -i:IP    Local IP address to listen on\n");
printf("       -n:x     Number of times to send message\n");
printf("       -b:x     Size of buffer to send\n\n");
ExitProcess(1);
}

//
// Function: ValidateArgs
//
// Description:
//    Parse the command line arguments, and set some global flags to
//    indicate what actions to perform
//
void ValidateArgs(int argc, char **argv) 
{
int                i;

for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    if ((argv[i][0] == '-') || (argv[i][0] == '/'))
    {
        switch (tolower(argv[i][1]))
        {
            case 'p':   // Local port
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > 3)
                    iPort = atoi(&argv[i][3]);
                break;
            case 'n':   // Number of times to receive message
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > 3)
                    dwCount = atol(&argv[i][3]);
                break;
            case 'b':   // Buffer size
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > 3)
                    dwLength = atol(&argv[i][3]);
                break;
            case 'i':   // Interface to receive datagrams on
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > 3)
                {
                    bInterface = TRUE;
                strcpy(szInterface, &argv[i][3]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                usage();
                break;
        }
    }
}
}

//
// Function: main
//
// Description:
//    Main thread of execution. Initialize Winsock, parse the command
//    line arguments, create a socket, bind it to a local interface
//    and port, and then read datagrams.
//
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
WSADATA        wsd;
SOCKET         s;
char          *recvbuf = NULL;
int            ret,
               i;
int          dwSenderSize;
SOCKADDR_IN    sender,
               local;

// Parse arguments and load Winsock
//
ValidateArgs(argc, argv);

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsd) != 0)
{
    printf("WSAStartup failed!\n");
    return 1;
}
// Create the socket and bind it to a local interface and port
//
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("socket() failed; %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_port = htons((short)iPort);
if (bInterface)
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(szInterface);
else
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
if (bind(s, (SOCKADDR *)&local, sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("bind() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
// Allocate the receive buffer
//
recvbuf = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, dwLength);
if (!recvbuf)
{
    printf("GlobalAlloc() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
// Read the datagrams
//

std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("file.txt");


for(i = 0; i < dwCount; i++)
{
    dwSenderSize = sizeof(sender);
    ret = recvfrom(s, recvbuf, dwLength, 0,
        (SOCKADDR *)&sender, &dwSenderSize);
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("recvfrom() failed; %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        break;
    }
    else if (ret == 0)
        break;
    else
    {
        recvbuf[ret] = '\0';
        printf("[%s] sent me: '%s'\n",
            inet_ntoa(sender.sin_addr), recvbuf);
        myfile << recvbuf<<endl;
    }
}
closesocket(s);

GlobalFree(recvbuf);
WSACleanup();
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the data after "DATA@" binary or character (printable) data?

Comment: it's binary data

Comment: *Always* check the returned value from `recvfrom` (and similar functions). It will tell you the exact amount of bytes that was received, *and* if there was an error. Going outside of the data that `recvfrom` wrote to the buffer will have you examining uninitialized and *indeterminate* data (unless you initialized the whole buffer) and that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I checked that, thanks.
So the value of recvfrom is 41.

I made a mistake in my post (that's because it was changing with every release od Xplane..) - the program is sending (5+n*36) bytes in one packet

Comment: The word is 'packet', not 'package', but actually it should be 'datagram' as this is UDP.

Comment: yes, I noticed I've been doing that mistake. Obviously- packet

Answer (score 0):

```
printf( "%s\n", package );
```

This is a C-style function that expects to get a C-style string, terminated by a `\0` byte.

The shown code allocates this `package` buffer with `new`, and fails to clear or initialize this buffer. The initial contents of `package` are, therefore, random garbage. The shown code then receives some data in the buffer:

```
recvfrom(mySocket, package, LEN, 0, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, &server_length);
```

`recvfrom`() returns the actual number of bytes received, but the shown code completely ignores that. As such, whatever actually gets received gets placed into the `package`, with the rest of the `package` buffer still containing the aforementioned random garbage, that it initially contained.

There's nothing in the shown code that correctly appends a `\0` after the last byte in the received packet. Consequently, when the shown code attempts to `printf` the `package` pointer, the actual contents that were `recvfrom()` will be followed by whatever random garbage was in the buffer, until `printf` finds, by luck of a draw, some `\0`, somewhere in there.

Comment: Every packet sent by Xplane is null-terminated.
I have been trying filling in `package` with zeros or other values and after it goes through `recvfrom()` it doens't print those zeros or other calues but still gives the same result

Comment: @dwid And the sender sends the terminator? It doesn't just send e.g. `strlen(...)` bytes, but `strlen(...) + 1`?

Comment: I must say I am not sure...
I wrote another simple app to get this data in python. And that's what I get after converting values to int:
received message:[  68.   65.   84.   65.   64.    3.    0.    0.    0.   96.  111.   63.
    65.    1.  253.   66.   65.  205.  252.   66.   65.  216.  164.   66.
    65.    0.  192.  121.  196.  175.   76.   92.   65.   59.   99.   96.
    65.   60.   99.   96.   65.]

Comment: And this is a quote from one Xplane UDP tutorial:
"A typical DATA packet being sent out from X-Plane may look something like:

      68 65 84 65 38 0 0 0 37 68 151 111 166 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"

Comment: @dwd Make up your mind. You said in comments above that the data is binary. You can't null-terminate binary.

Comment: @EJP my bad, sorry.

Comment: Note that relying on the sending program to always NUL-terminate the data for you means that a buggy (or malicious) sender program could cause your receiving program to invoke Undefined Behavior simply by sending you a data packet that doesn't contain any 0 bytes in it.  Therefore you'd be well-advised to either check the incoming data to be sure it is NUL-terminated, or at least place your own 0 byte at the end of the received-data buffer, just to be sure.

Comment: `ret=recvfrom(mySocket, package, LEN, 0, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, &server_length);
package[ret] = '\0'`

I've done this. In my case `ret==41`, so 42nd element of `package` is going to be overwritten by`'\0'`.

Am I correct here?
It still doesn't work after this little change.

Comment: Just saying 'my bad' does *not* constitute making up your mind. You need to clarify which it is.

Comment: It is what I posted above. It's not binary, I made a mistake.